# How to create single profile for each multiple user?

Tags: django, django-models

My app has two different user. 'Teacher' and 'Student'. I want to create profile for each user. 'Student's profile' for student and 'Teacher's profile' for teacher. I'm using post_signal to create 'Student's profile' and 'Teacher's Profile' but when a student user or a teacher signs up, two profiles are created, 'Teacher's profile' and 'Student's Profile'. Is there some logic to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate two models and create separately and then you can handle form to assign children to teacher.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.teacher = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

it's a sample class base view